# Make Jetty Container AUTH return different headers

Tags: maven, http-headers, jetty

Currently I have a working system where I need a minor change. I want to change the headers returned when a user is not logged in making a rest-call. Currently it's always returning a WWW-Authenticate: Basic header that auto-pops up the browsers login.

I want to change this into something else that does not fire this (so no basic/digest). This seems however impossible to achieve with the jetty-maven-plugin as web.xml filters do work but they fire after a person is inside the program. I want the filters to work in the very jetty himself.

Currently I have the RewriteHeaders found and working however they only add, not rewrite the header.

```
<Set name="handler">
    <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
            <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                <Item>
                    <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
                </Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>
</Set>

<Get id="oldhandler" name="handler"/>

<Set name="handler">
    <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
        <Set name="handler">
            <Ref id="oldhandler"/>
        </Set>

        <!-- Add Acces-Control-Allow-Origin -->
        <Call name="addRule">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                    <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                    <Set name="name">Access-Control-Allow-Origin</Set>
                    <Set name="value">http://localhost:1337</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>

        <!-- Change the WWW-Authenticate into something non digest/basic -->
        <Call name="addRule">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                    <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                    <Set name="name">WWW-Authenticate</Set>
                    <Set name="value">NotBasic</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </New>
</Set>
```

Long story short... how to get the HeaderPatternRule overwrite instead of adding things in the header only?

Comment: To add to this question. We are using JAASLoginService with a LoginModule. There is a BasicAuthenticator that instantly returns a header with this WWW-Authenticate: basic  ..., We want to overwrite this. But writing a custom class that will always result into a class-not-found exception.

Therefor we want this HeaderPatternRule to overwrite this to a non-basic/digest header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication occurs *before* all of your webapp's servlets and filters.

You'll either need to not use Servlet security and authentication (doing everything in your own webapp), or write a custom Authentication implementation to support your use case.

Comment: Correct and to add to this: the filter seems to be working however the BasicAuthenticator does overwrite the WWW-Authenticate again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom Authenticator to replace the BasicAuthenticator.  You can base your code on the BasicAuthenticator and then change the headers you want it to operate with.

Alternately don't use any container authentication and write Filter that implements your authentication mechanism and uses the login method on request.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of implementation via XML and a custom made authenticator class? I could net get it working; getting classNotFoundExceptions.